# Form submit handlers with additional arguments

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi

For some requirement I need to pass additional information to form submit handler. In form api, while defining custom submit handler as

```
$additional_args = array();
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_submit_handler'
```

I expect to submit handler as

```
function my_submit_handler($form, &$form_state, $additional_args){
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The submit handler is called by the drupal fapi, so you can't do something like that. Instead what you can do, is to add what you need, either to the `$form`, or to the `$form_state`. The usual approaches is to:

- Added a field to the form, type value to store the value. Don't do this if you have the value in the form definition.

  ```
  $form['store'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $value
  );
  ```

  This  will be available in `$form_state['values']['store']`.
- Add the value to `$form_state['storage']`, done if you variables in your validation handle you want to transfer to your submit handler:

  ```
  // Validation.
  $form_state['storage']['value'] = $value;

  ...

  // Submit
  $value = $form_state['storage']['value'];
  // Need to unset stored values when not used anymore.
  unset($form_state['storage']['value']);
  ```

Comment: Note that as of Drupal 6, you can also simply store arbitrary variables in $form['#foo'] instead, as long as '#foo' does not conflict with any other internal property of the Form API.

Answer (score 9):

Drupal 7: Custom arguments are automatically propagated troug $form_state['build_info']['args']
This is said in http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7

Ex:

```
hook_form($form, &$form_state, $myAdditionnalArg) {...}
```

Then  in

```
hook_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
```

...
`//$form_state['build_info']['args']` is an array containing at index 0 the value of argument `$myAdditionnalArg`
...

Answer (score 4):

As reported in [$form['#submit'] and $form['#validate'] and $form['#process'] no longer support custom parameters](http://drupal.org/node/144132#custom-params), the suggested way to pass parameters to a submission handler set as in the shown code is to use code similar to the following:

```
$form['#first_paramater'] = $value;
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_submit_handler';
```

The handler would retrieve the value as `$form['#first_paramater']`.
To notice that, instead of `#first_paramater`, the code can use a different string, but it must start with `#`.

Normally it's not necessary to set a submission handler like the code does, but there are some cases where it is necessary, like to alter a form created by another module, or to set a different submission handler for each of the submission buttons present in a form.

[drupal_retrieve_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_retrieve_form/6) saves the parameters passed to the form build handler in `$form['#parameters']` which contains:

- `$form_id`
- `$form_state`
- parameters passed to the form builder